# Add row in html table dynamically

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

I want to add row dinamically in my html table , then  save the new row in my database with servlet.
how can i get the row in my servlet .please help me

Comment: i have this program code but it only in jsp page you need than i post here

Comment: in this code multiple row add dynamically you change code yourself and use in your project..

Answer (score 1):

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE> Add/Remove dynamic rows in HTML table </TITLE>
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
    function addRow(tableID) {

        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var element1 = document.createElement("input");
        element1.type = "checkbox";
        element1.name="chkbox[]";
        cell1.appendChild(element1);

        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        cell2.innerHTML = rowCount + 1;

        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        var element2 = document.createElement("input");
        element2.type = "text";
        element2.name = "txtbox[]";
        cell3.appendChild(element2);


    }

    function deleteRow(tableID) {
        try {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;

        for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
            var row = table.rows[i];
            var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
            if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                table.deleteRow(i);
                rowCount--;
                i--;
            }


        }
        }catch(e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    }

</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />

<INPUT type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />

<TABLE id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">
    <TR>
        <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk"/></TD>
        <TD> 1 </TD>
        <TD> <INPUT type="text" /> </TD>
    </TR>
</TABLE>

</BODY>
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answers but my problem is how to store the new line added to the database. (I'm looking for how to recover a servelet or in a jsp code). there is not a simpler code than the code of @IREN

Comment: how to implement jquery autocomplete on input type text using this tutorial

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this code   

 <%@page import="javax.xml.crypto.Data"%>
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
    <%@ page import="java.util.*" %>  

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <%Connection con =null; %>
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Test</title>
        <%
            //Connection con;
            Statement s=null;
            ResultSet rs=null;


            String url = "";

            try 
            {
                Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            } 
            catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfex) 
            {
                cnfex.printStackTrace();
            }

            String sql = "select * from tbPresicription";
            try 
            {
                    s = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

                    rs =s.executeQuery(sql);
                    while(rs.next())
                    {
                    //  System.out.println("Name : "+rs.getString("PresicriptionIDP"));
                    }

                    System.out.println(" rs --> " + rs.first());
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Hello :"+e);
            }
        %>
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

                            i=1;
                            a=1;
                            function addRow()
                            {
                                //Row Insert....

                                var table=document.getElementById("dataTable");
                                var row1=table.insertRow();
                                var row2=table.insertRow();
                                var row3=table.insertRow();
                                var row4=table.insertRow();

                                //Cell Insert Start     

                                var cell1=row1.insertCell(0);
                                cell1.rowSpan="4";
                                cell1.innerHTML="";
                                cell1.align="center";
                                cell1.style.width = "30px";
                                cell1.innerHTML=i++;

                                //DropDownList

                                var cell1=row2.insertCell(0);
                                var abc=document.createElement("input");
                                abc.id="CompanyName"+a;

                                var Company=document.createElement("label");
                                Company.innerHTML ="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Brand:&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                                Company.style.width = "10px";
                                var Select = document.createElement('select');
                                var opt1 = document.createElement('option');

                                <% try
                                    {
                                        System.out.println(" rs --> click  " + rs.first());
                                            String IDP = null;
                                            String Name=null;

                                %>
                                             opt1.value="";
                                             opt1.text="----Select Tablet----";
                                             Select.appendChild(opt1);  
                                <%
                                                while (rs.next()) 
                                                {
                                                    IDP = rs.getString("PresicriptionIDP")+":"+rs.getString("BrandName")+":"+rs.getString("Generic")+":"+rs.getString("Info")+":"+rs.getString("Dosage")+":"+rs.getString("Days")+":"+rs.getString("Qauntity")+":"+rs.getString("DosageInfo")+":"+rs.getString("TabletName")+":";
                                                    Name=rs.getString("TabletName");
                                                //  System.out.println("IDP :"+IDP+"Name is :"+Name);
                                %>
                                                        var opt2=document.createElement("option");
                                                        opt2.value="<%= IDP %>";
                                                        opt2.text="<%= Name %>";
                                                        Select.appendChild(opt2);
                                <%
                                                }
                                     }
                                     catch(Exception e)
                                     { 
                                            e.printStackTrace(); 
                                     }
                                %>

                                        Select.name="opt"+a;
                                        Select.required="required";
                                        Select.id="opt"+a;
                                        var optid = "opt"+a;
                                        var id=Select.id;
                                        Select.setAttribute('onChange',"javascript:SelectItem(this.value,id);");
                                        Select.style.width = "150px";
                                        Company.readOnly = 'readonly';
                                        cell1.appendChild(Select);
                                        cell1.appendChild(Company);
                                        cell1.appendChild(abc);

                                //Days Detail

                                var cell3=row2.insertCell(1);
                                var Days=document.createElement("input");
                                var Days1=document.createElement("label");
                                Days.type = "text";
                                Days1.innerHTML ="Days:&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                                Days.name = "Days"+a;
                                Days.id="Days"+a;
                                Days.style.width = "30px";
                                cell3.rowSpan="2";
                                cell3.style.width = "83px";
                                cell3.appendChild(Days1);
                                cell3.appendChild(Days);

                                //Generic Detail

                                var cell1=row3.insertCell(0);
                                var Generic=document.createElement("input");
                                var Generic1 = document.createElement("label");
                                Generic.type = "text";
                                Generic1.innerHTML = "Generic:&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                                Generic.name = "Generic"+a;
                                Generic.id = "Generic"+a;
                                Generic.style.width = "357px";
                                Generic.readOnly = 'readonly';
                                cell1.appendChild(Generic1);
                                cell1.appendChild(Generic);

                                //Dose Deside

                                var cell2=row2.insertCell(1);
                                var Dosage=document.createElement("input");
                                var Dosage1 = document.createElement("label");
                                Dosage.type = "text";
                                Dosage1.innerHTML = "Dosage:&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                                Dosage.name = "Dosage"+a;
                                Dosage.id = "Dosage"+a;
                                Dosage.style.width = "80px";
                                cell2.rowSpan = "2";
                                cell2.appendChild(Dosage1);
                                cell2.appendChild(Dosage);

                                //Medicine Info                         

                                var cell1=row4.insertCell(0);
                                var Info=document.createElement("input");
                                var Info1 = document.createElement("label");
                                Info.type = "text";
                                Info1.innerHTML = "Info:&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                                Info.name = "Info"+a;
                                Info.id = "Info"+a;
                                Info.readOnly = 'readonly';
                                Info.style.width = "500px";
                                cell1.style.width = "400px";
                                cell1.appendChild(Info1);
                                cell1.appendChild(Info);
                                cell1.colSpan="2";

                                //Medicine Dose Info...

                                var cell2 = row4.insertCell(1);
                                var DosageInfo = document.createElement("input");
                                var DosageInfo1 = document.createElement("label");
                                DosageInfo.type = "text";
                                DosageInfo1.innerHTML = "DosageInfo:&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                                DosageInfo.name = "DosageInfo"+a;
                                DosageInfo.id = "DosageInfo"+a;
                                DosageInfo.style.width = "170px";
                                DosageInfo.readOnly = 'readonly';
                                cell2.colSpan = "2";
                                cell2.appendChild(DosageInfo1);
                                cell2.appendChild(DosageInfo);

                                //Medicine Qauntity define..

                                var cell4=row2.insertCell(3);
                                var Qauntity = document.createElement("input");
                                var Qauntity1 = document.createElement("label");
                                Qauntity.type = "text";
                                Qauntity1.innerHTML = "Qauntity:&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                                Qauntity.name = "Qauntity"+a;
                                Qauntity.id = "Qauntity"+a;
                                Qauntity.style.width = "30px";
                                cell4.appendChild(Qauntity1);
                                cell4.appendChild(Qauntity);
                                cell4.rowSpan="2";

                                a++;
                            }

                            function SelectItem(val,id)
                            {

                                //alert('val : '+val);
                                var id1=id.substring(3);
                                //alert('id1 : '+id1);
                                var aa=val.split(":");
                                document.getElementById("CompanyName"+id1).value=aa[1];
                                document.getElementById("Generic"+id1).value=aa[2];
                                document.getElementById("Info"+id1).value=aa[3];
                                document.getElementById("Dosage"+id1).value=aa[4];
                                document.getElementById("Days"+id1).value=aa[5];
                                document.getElementById("Qauntity"+id1).value=aa[6];
                                document.getElementById("DosageInfo"+id1).value=aa[7];
                            }

                            function removeRow()
                            {
                                document.getElementById("dataTable").deleteRow(this);
                            }

                        </script>

                        <script type="text/javascript">

                        function addData()
                        {
                            //alert('hii : '+a);
                            var i;
                            var ss=0;
                            for(i=1;i<a;i++)
                                {
                                //  alert('Hiiii : '+i);
                                    var TabletName1=document.getElementById("opt"+i).value;
                                    var CompanyName=document.getElementById("CompanyName"+i).value;
                                    var Generic=document.getElementById("Generic"+i).value;
                                    var Info=document.getElementById("Info"+i).value;
                                    var Dosage=document.getElementById("Dosage"+i).value;
                                    var Days=document.getElementById("Days"+i).value;
                                    var Qauntity=document.getElementById("Qauntity"+i).value;
                                    var DosageInfo=document.getElementById("DosageInfo"+i).value;

                                    ss = ss+TabletName1;
                                }
                                //  alert('TabletName1='+ss);
                                    window.location.replace("index.jsp?name="+ss);                      

                            <%

                            int i=0;
                            String a = null;

                            try
                            {
                                String name=request.getParameter("name");
                                System.out.println("Name  :"+name);

                                String data[]=name.split(":");

                                int size=data.length;
                                int size1=(size-1)/2;

                                String BrandName[]=new String[size1];   
                                String TabletName[]=new String[size1];
                                String Generic[]=new String[size1];
                                String info[]=new String[size1];
                                String dosage[]=new String[size1];
                                String days[]=new String[size1];
                                String Qty[]=new String[size1];
                                String DosageInfo[]=new String[size1];
                                String PresicriptionIDP[]=new String[size1];

                                int x=0;

                                for(i=0;i<size+2;i++)
                                {
                                    PresicriptionIDP[x]=data[i];
                                    i++;
                                    //System.out.println("PresicriptionIDP : "+PresicriptionIDP[x]);

                                    BrandName[x]=data[i];
                                    i++;
                                    //System.out.println("BrandName : "+BrandName[x]);

                                    Generic[x]=data[i];
                                    i++;
                                    //System.out.println("Generic : "+Generic[x]);

                                    info[x]=data[i];
                                    i++;
                                    //System.out.println("info : "+info[x]);

                                    dosage[x]=data[i];
                                    i++;
                                    //System.out.println("dosage : "+dosage[x]);

                                    days[x]=data[i];
                                    i++;
                                    //System.out.println("days  : "+days[x]);

                                    Qty[x]=data[i];
                                    i++;
                                    //System.out.println("Qty :"+Qty[x]);

                                    DosageInfo[x]=data[i];
                                    i++;
                                    //System.out.println("DosageInfo : "+DosageInfo[x]);

                                    TabletName[x]=data[i];
                                    i++;
                                    //System.out.println("TabletName : "+TabletName[x]);

                                    System.out.println("\n Value of : "+i);

                                    x++;

                                    System.out.println("Value of X="+x);


                                    for(int ss=0;ss<x;ss++)
                                    {
                                        String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO tbPrescriptionNew"
                                                + "(PresicriptionIDP, TabletName, BrandName, Generic,Info,Dosage,Days,Qauntity,DosageInfo) VALUES"
                                                + "(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                                        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);

                                        preparedStatement.setString(1, PresicriptionIDP[ss]);
                                        System.out.println("\n PresicriptionIDP" +PresicriptionIDP[ss]);

                                        preparedStatement.setString(2, TabletName[ss]);
                                        System.out.println("\n TabletName=" +TabletName[ss]);

                                        preparedStatement.setString(3, BrandName[ss]);
                                        System.out.println("\n BrandName=" +BrandName[ss]);

                                        preparedStatement.setString(4, Generic[ss]);
                                        System.out.println("\n Generic=" +Generic[ss]);

                                        preparedStatement.setString(5, info[ss]);
                                        System.out.println("\n info=" +info[ss]);

                                        preparedStatement.setString(6, dosage[ss]);
                                        System.out.println("\n dosage=" +dosage[ss]);

                                        preparedStatement.setString(7, days[ss]);
                                        System.out.println("\n days=" +days[ss]);

                                        preparedStatement.setString(8, Qty[ss]);
                                        System.out.println("\n Qty=" +Qty[ss]);

                                        preparedStatement.setString(9, DosageInfo[ss]);
                                        System.out.println("\n DosageInfo=" +DosageInfo[ss]);

                                        // execute insert SQL stetement
                                        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            catch(Exception e)
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            %>                      

                            }

                        </script>

        </head>
        <body>
                <center>
                        <input type="button" class="selectItem"  onClick="addRow('dataTable')" value = "AddRow">
                        <input type='button' value='Delete'  onclick="removeRow()"/>
                </center>

                <table id="dataTable" border="1" width="894px;" align="center">

                </table>

                <input type="button" onClick="addData()" value = "AddData"> 
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: thank you for your answers but my problem is how to store the new line added to the database. (I'm looking for how to recover a servelet or in a jsp code).
there is not a simpler code than the code of @IREN

Comment: in this code row add in database with data after access from database

Comment: This "answer" is terrible. You're posting code without explaining what it does, you're recommending using Java scriplets within a jsp, and you're not using Java naming conventions.